# SQL: IN vs EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle10g, exists

I read that normally you should use `EXISTS` when the results of the subquery are large, and `IN` when the subquery results are small.

But it would seem to me that it's also relevant if a subquery has to be re-evaluated for each row, or if it can be evaluated once for the entire query.

Consider the following example of two equivalent queries:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE attr IN
(SELECT attr FROM t2
WHERE attr2 = ?);

SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM t2
WHERE t1.attr = t2.attr
AND attr2 = ?);
```

The former subquery can be evaluated once for the entire query, the latter has to be evaluated for each row.

Assume that the results of the subquery are very large. Which would be the best way to write this?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan for each? I would be willing to wager that they are both exactly the same regardless of the size of the number of results in the subquery.

Comment: On around 50000 records, check execution time for both queries and compare it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. Especially as in Oracle you can convert every EXISTS clause into an IN clause and vice versa, because Oracle's IN clause can deal with tuples (`where (abc) in (select x,y,z from ...`), which most other dbms cannot.

And your reasoning is good. Yes, with the IN clause you suggest to load all the subquery's data once instead of looking up the records in a loopg. However this is just partly true, because:

- As good as it seems to get all subquery data selected just once, the outer query must loop through the resulting array for every record. This can be quite slow, because it's just an array. If Oracle looks up data in a table instead there are often indexes to help it, so the nested loop with repeated table lookups is eventually faster.
- Oracle's optimizer re-writes queries. So it can come to the same execution plan for the two statements or even get to quite unexpected plans. You never know ;-)
- Oracle might decide not to loop at all. It may decide for a hash join instead, which works completely different and is usually very effective.

Having said this, Oracle's optimizer should notice that the two statements are exactly the same actually and should generate the same execution plan. But experience shows that the optimizer sometimes doesn't notice, and quite often the optimizer does better with the EXISTS clause for whatever reason. (Not as much difference as in MySQL, but still, EXISTS seems preferable over IN in Oracle, too.)

So as to your question "Assume that the results of the subquery are very large. Which would be the best way to write this?", it is unlikely for the IN clause to be faster than the EXISTS clause.

I often like the IN clause better for its simplicity and mostly find it a bit more readable. But when it comes to performance, it is sometimes better to use EXISTS (or even outer joins for that matter).